# Mysql wont start after changing temp dir on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I run ubuntu 12.04.
I am trying to move the temp dir for files as `/tmp` has filled up, somehow I only set it to 1meg, which is obviously not enough for a large mysql database.

What I need to do is move it on, so I looked online for a solution to this and I found an article which seems to make sense.
In the `my.conf` file at `/etc/mysql/my.conf` I changed the tmpdir directive to `/mysqltmp`.   I made the directory with root login, then `chmod 777` that dir. I reboot and the mysql server wont start. (it was starting just previously).

The error log says..

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/mysqltmp/ibqADloJ'
```

It's a permissions error, however the directory has full permissions so why is this a problem?

Comment: This was correct.  I put it in /var/lib/mysql/tmp instead and it worked fine. If you want to make an official answer I will +1 it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably apparmor is getting in your way. Have a look at `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` and make your new temp-folder writable by the mysqld process (or configure mysqld to write its temporary data to a directory it has write permissions for)